# Equivalent to TeamCity service messages in Azure DevOps (for custom test results)

Tags: build, azure-devops, automated-tests, teamcity

TeamCity supports ["service messages" to report test results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Reporting+Tests) for a non-standard test suite.  The custom test script prints things like `##teamcity[testStarted name='testName' captureStandardOutput='true']` and similar to report the test results.

Is there an equivalent functionality in Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with **JamesD** that [Logging Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#build-commands) in Azure Devops is equivalent to [Service Messages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html) in TeamCity.

But for now `Logging Commands` doesn't support 'Reporting Tests' action, this makes a difference. In Azure Devops you can consider logging the test-related into into TEXT file(echo of CMD, Out-File or PS) or other format file, and then use [Upload log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#uploadlog-upload-a-log) or [Upload summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary) command to display the test-related info.

**Eg:**

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]filepath"
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=TestSummary;]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\filepath"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the definitive reference for the various service messages that Azure Pipelines supports:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Taken from the above site, the general syntax is:

> The general format for a logging command is:
>
> `##vso[area.action property1=value;property2=value;...]message`
>
> To invoke a logging command, simply emit the command via standard
> output. For example, from a PowerShell task:
>
> `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`